# asp.net Resource.resx

Tags: asp.net

my web app has Resource.resx there for my website name convention. everything works just fine. I have Lblcompany as name and "test" as Value

Now, I have separate wcf project and I added the my web app reference there.
my questions. how can I call the content from the resource.resx like I need to call
Lblcompany and get the value which is 'test' in this case?

Answer (score 1):

They are different applications (website and wcf), so you need copy and compile the resource.resx in the wcf project.